# CNN Issues with Max Pooling

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, max-pooling

I have a dataset of 40X40X7 images. I have the following model architecture and implementation.

```
def conv_block(inputs, n_filter, regularizer, common_args):
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=n_filter,
                               kernel_size=3,
                               strides=1,
                               padding='same',
                               activation='relu',
                               kernel_regularizer=regularizer,
                               **common_args)(inputs)  
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=n_filter,
                               kernel_size=3,
                               strides=1,
                               padding='same',
                               activation='relu',
                               kernel_regularizer=regularizer,
                               **common_args)(inputs)  
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
    return x

def dense_block(inputs, n_filter, regularizer, drop_rate, common_args):
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32 * n_filter,
                              activation='relu',
                              kernel_regularizer=regularizer,
                              **common_args)(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(drop_rate)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32 * n_filter,
                              activation='relu',
                              kernel_regularizer=regularizer,
                              **common_args)(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(drop_rate)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8 * n_filter, activation='relu',
                              kernel_regularizer=regularizer,
                              **common_args)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(drop_rate)(x)
    return x

def make_level_model(img_size, n_bands, l2, nf, dr, seed):
    regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2)
    initializer = tf.keras.initializers.glorot_normal(seed=seed)
    common_args = {"kernel_initializer": initializer}

    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(img_size, img_size, n_bands))
    x = conv_block(inputs, nf, regularizer, common_args)
    x = conv_block(x, nf * 2, regularizer, common_args)
    x = conv_block(x, nf * 4, regularizer, common_args)

    x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
    x = dense_block(x, nf, regularizer, dr, common_args)
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, **common_args)(x)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
    return model

# Define the hyperparameters
l2 = 1e-5
lr = 1e-4
bs = 64
ds = 200
nf = 32
dr = 0.5
img_size = 40
n_bands = 7
epochs = 200
with_feature = False
seed = 42

# Define the learning rate schedule
lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.InverseTimeDecay(
    lr,
    decay_steps=train_count*bs,
    decay_rate=1,
    staircase=True)

# Define the optimizer
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr_schedule)

# Create the model
model = make_level_model(img_size, n_bands, l2, nf, dr,seed)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="mean_squared_error", metrics=[RSquare()])

# Train the model
history = model.fit(
    train_dataset.batch(bs),
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=val_dataset.batch(bs),
    callbacks=[
        tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
            filepath='Ageb200040by40Patch/weights.best.model_3Kernel_2000target120002conv2dense2.hdf5',
            monitor='val_r_square', mode='max', save_weights_only=True, save_best_only=True),
        tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_r_square', min_delta=0, patience=epochs // 2,
                                         mode='max')
    ]
)
```

I keep getting the following error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) /tmp/ipykernel_8133/4129889730.py in <cell line: 25>()
> 23
> 24 # Create the model
> ---> 25 model = make_level_model(img_size, n_bands, l2, nf, dr,seed)
> 26 model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="mean_squared_error", metrics=[RSquare()])
> 27
>
> /tmp/ipykernel_8133/1120897256.py in make_level_model(img_size,
> n_bands, l2, nf, dr, seed)
> 7     x = conv_block(inputs, nf, regularizer, common_args)
> 8     x = conv_block(x, nf * 2, regularizer, common_args)
> ----> 9     x = conv_block(x, nf * 4, regularizer, common_args)
> 10
> 11     x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
>
> /tmp/ipykernel_8133/1783471186.py in conv_block(inputs, n_filter,
> regularizer, common_args)
> 14                                kernel_regularizer=regularizer,
> 15                                **common_args)(inputs)
> ---> 16     x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
> 17     return x
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py
> in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
> 68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
> 69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
> ---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
> 71         finally:
> 72             del filtered_tb
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py
> in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def,
> extract_traceback)    1965   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
> 1966     # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
> -> 1967     raise ValueError(e.message)    1968     1969   # Record the current Python stack trace as the creating stacktrace of this
>
> ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer
> "max_pooling2d_29" (type MaxPooling2D).
>
> Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node
> max_pooling2d_29/MaxPool}} = MaxPoolT=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW",
> explicit_paddings=[], ksize=[1, 1, 2, 2], padding="VALID", strides=[1,
> 1, 2, 2]' with input shapes: [?,128,10,1].
>
> Call arguments received by layer "max_pooling2d_29" (type
> MaxPooling2D):   • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 128, 10, 1),
> dtype=float32)

I am not sure what is the issue. I think I have a big enough size for the images at 40X40X7.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves your problem, but it looks like that your second convolution is operating once more on `inputs` instead of `x` (on which it should I assume). The same is true for your second dense layer.

Make sure, the `data_format` parameter of your MaxPool2D is set correct and your input dataframe `train_dataset` is also truely 40X40X7 and you did not mix any channels.

Comment: I changed the convolution layer and dense layer. The train dataset is a tuple of image and label. Image is of size 40X40X7